# Filtering a collection by property in object in nested collection

Tags: c#, linq

I have three classes:

```
public class Error
{
    public List<ErrorOccurrenceDetails> Occurrences { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class ErrorOccurrenceDetails
{
    public Dictionary<DateTime, ErrorTime> Times { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class ErrorTime
{
    public string Version { get; set; }
}
```

There's an `Error` that has multiple `Occurrences` that happened in different `Times`. Each time can occur on a different `Version`.

I have a list of `Error`s. I need to remove errors which *do not* have provided version, for example if user only wants to see errors in version "1.0", other versions (such as "1.1", "1.2") need to be removed. However, if an error has occurrences on version "1.0" AND others, filter should delete only bad occurrences, not entire error.

I tried to do it this way:

```
private IList<Error> errors;

private void Filter(string filterVersion)
{
    var errorsToRemove = new Dictionary<int, ErrorOccurrenceDetails>();
    foreach (Error error in this.errors) 
    {
        int index = this.errors.IndexOf(error);
        var listOfSearchedItems = error.Occurences.ToList();
        listOfSearchedItems.RemoveAll(x => x.Times.Values.Any(y => y.Version != filterVersion));

        var errorOccurences = error.Occurences.Except(listOfSearchedItems).ToList();
        if (errorsToRemove.ContainsKey(index))
        {
            errorsToRemove[index].AddRange(errorOccurences);
        }
        else
        {
            errorsToRemove.Add(index, errorOccurences);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to put all errors that need to be removed into `errorsToRemove` dictionary, where key is error index in `this.errors`, and value is a list of occurrences not on searched version.
It *kinda* works, but sometimes doesn't remove bad versions and causes some correct versions to also be removed, so there is a hole I haven't noticed.

**Sample error list in this fiddle:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/Kxq50i

Comment: Some demo data that reproduces the issue would be helpful.

Comment: @Flater I'm on it.

Comment: @Flater https://dotnetfiddle.net/Kxq50i

Comment: Part of the reason I mentioned test data is to specifically highlight what it is you want. Problems like there are very commonly solved by finding the difference between you describing _precisely_ what you want (which can be shown with a specific example, and the logic you wrote. Right now, your explanation isn't quite clear to me (e.g. are you filtering out the bad version, or are you removing anything that has _any_ mention of a bad version, even if it also has good mentions?) and I can't derive your intention from your code (since the code clearly doesn't do what you want it to).

Comment: @Flater: You are absolutely right, the question is not clear yet and, thus, my answer is probably wrong. Deleted it. OP: Please provide some input samples in your question with both *expected result* and *actual result*.

Comment: @Heinzi I managed to read your answer before you deleted it and it actually helped me a lot. I realized I added a lot of unnecessary steps.

Comment: @xtul: That's good to hear, thanks for the feedback! It's also great that you self-answered your question with your solution, but please copy & paste your new Filter method in your answer. Here on StackOverflow we like answers to be "self-contained", i.e., useful without having to follow external links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Heinzi's answer I decided to use a much simpler approach. I think I wanted to avoid `Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute` exception at all costs and started doing stupid things.

```
private IList<Error> errors;

private static void Filter(string filterVersion)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < errors.Count; index++) 
    {
        Error error = errors[index];
        foreach (var occurrence in error.Occurrences)
        {
            var toRemove = occurrence.Times.Keys.Where(key => occurrence.Times[key].Version != filterVersion).ToList();
            foreach (var key in toRemove)
            {
                occurrence.Times.Remove(key);
            }

            if (occurrence.Times.Count == 0)
            {
                 errors[index] = null; // not deleted to prevent index shift, null is hidden in UI
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The solution is updated [in this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Kxq50i).

Answer (score 0):

The reason might be the following lines which might cause the items of the original `error.Occurences` to be removed:

```
var listOfSearchedItems = error.Occurences.ToList();
listOfSearchedItems.RemoveAll(x => x.Times.Values.Any(y => y.Version != filterVersion));
```

Try replacing those 2 lines with the one below:

```
var listOfSearchedItems = error.Occurences.Where(x => x.Times.Values.Any(y => y.Version == filterVersion)); // Note: Here we also replaced the "!=" with "=="
```

Answer (score 0):

When using Linq, it is easier to think in terms of what to *include* rather than what you want to *remove* and write your code that way. For example:

```
private static IList<Error> Filter(string filterVersion)
{
    var filtered = errors.Where(error => error.Occurrences.Any(occurrence => occurrence.Times.Any(kvp => kvp.Value.Version == filterVersion)))
        .Select(error =>
        {
            return new Error
            {
                Occurrences = error.Occurrences
                    .Where(occurrence => occurrence.Times.Any(kvp => kvp.Value.Version == filterVersion))
                    .Select(occurrence => 
                    {
                        return new ErrorOccurrenceDetails
                        {
                            Times = new Dictionary<DateTime, ErrorTime>(occurrence.Times.Where(kvp => kvp.Value.Version == filterVersion))
                        };
                    })
                    .ToList()
            };
        })
        .ToList();
    return filtered;
}
```

Another possible benefit of this approach is that you are not modifying your original data, so you can apply different filters without having to re-read it.